# How to convert svg to eps using Imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert svg image to eps using Imagemagick. I am able to convert the image using Imagemagick, but the image size is too high when compared to the original image size and the content is not displayed correctly compared to the svg.

Answer (score 8):

I was just wondering this too. However, it appears that Imagemagick might not be the best tool to do this.

Imagemagick is a "raster image processor," but SVG and EPS are vector formats. So using Imagemagick will cause those images to lose information as it has to convert from a vector format, to a raster format, and then back to vector. This probably explains why the contents of your image aren't correctly displayed.

Maybe consider using Inkscape to do this conversion using the following

```
# Works as of Version 0.92.4
inkscape ing.svg \
    -E out.eps \
    --export-ignore-filters \
    --export-ps-level=3
```

where the `-E` flag is short for `--export-eps` to export EPS files.

Source:

- http://imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#vector
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30539923/6873133

Comment: Just to notice that the `-E` option should be replaced with `-o` with recent versions of Inkscape.

Comment: @robin850 which version are you thinking about? I'm looking at the man page for Inkscape and can't find that option yet https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html

Comment: Currently with 1.0beta2 ; I'm on macOS but I guess the options are the same across operating systems.

Comment: @robin850 ah okay. The current version is 0.92.4, so that might be it. I'll update my answer to reflect the versioning and maybe update it in the future whenever Inkscape goes 1.0