# Inkscape command line: Need to convert SVG to eps without filter rasterisation

Tags: svg, eps, inkscape

I need to convert an SVG to EPS and currently use inkscape to do this.

To convert the SVG using the Inkscape GUI version, I simply open the svg, and "Save As" 'logo.eps', unselecting the "Rasterize filter effects" option.

[image: picture]

However, I want to automate this process using the command line. 
         Using

`inkscape logo.svg -E logo.eps`

works but does not disable filter rasterisation. I have done some research but can't figure out how to do this can anyone provide me the correct command? Thanks

Answer (score 54):

The command I had to use to fix this problem was

```
inkscape in.svg -E out.eps --export-ignore-filters --export-ps-level=3
```

where in.svg is your image and out.eps is the eps that comes out.

#### Edit

As suggested by Vladimir in comments, newer versions of inkscape doesn't have `-E` option, so need to replace it with `-o`.

Comment: Side note for anyone struggling to get the above working: In and Out both require the absolute path (pwd).

Comment: From Mac OS, I had to run this: `/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape ~/Downloads/logo.svg -E ~/Downloads/logo-out.eps --export-ignore-filters --export-ps-level=3`

Comment: Cool, this even preserves the text in the input SVG file!

Comment: Inkscape v.1.0.2 gives "Unknown option -E" error. I have replaced "-E" with "-o" (output) and it is okay now.

Comment: For Inkscape 1.0.2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15), I used: `inkscape file.svg --export-type=eps file.eps --export-ignore-filters --export-ps-level=3`; Otherwise I got `Unknown option -E`

Comment: this command is definitely rasterizing, just not as badly

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the game but google brought me here

Found part of this solution on a website that needed an account. This lets you convert all the files within a folder

```
for file in *.svg; do inkscape "$file" -E "${file%svg}eps" --export-ignore-filters --export-ps-level=3; done
```

Comment: On macOS (at least the old High Sierra) it works like a charm. Thank you.